# Can I ask WindowsPhone Approve team something like "expedited review" as it in Apple?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have app which was written for some event, and with Apple I make an expedited review request.

Does WindowsPhone have something like this?

Comment: You may ask here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ stackoverflow is more for concrete programming questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when uploading your application, you just need to write all you need in the message form.

[image: Developer center WP7]